# Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express - error in correct code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, class, compilation

I copied&pasted code from *The Programming Language 4th Edition 2013*:

[image: The Programming Language 4th Edition 2013, page 49]

to Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express and compiled. I got many errors, why? The version of compilator is old? I didn't have all code to run it?
[image: Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express]

Copying code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;


class vector{
public:
    vector(int s) :elem{new double[s]}, sz{s} {}
    double& operator[](int i) {return elem[i];}
    int size() {return sz;}
private:
    double* elem;
    int sz;
};


void main()
{
    vector v(6);
}
```

[EDIT]When I use Visual Studio 2013:

[image: Visual Studio 2013]

Comment: This uses at least one C++11 (11 for the year 2011) which wasn't available then.

Comment: To use C++11 features, you have to use Visual Studio 2012 or 2013.

Comment: Wow, `using namespace std;` and *then* you call your vector class, `vector`? Did you know that you've used the same name as `std::vector`? (as a note, there is no `using namespace` in the source image, and they use `Vector` with a capital V).

Comment: Yes, I only want to show example of my "problem".

Comment: In the VS2013 screenshot it looks like you have some funny symbol after `double`, isntead of `*`.  (Compare with the `*` in `_TCHAR*`). The first error message says that it is having trouble with tht `double? elem;` line.

Comment: Now, everything work! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented above, your syntax uses C++11, which is not available in Visual Studio 2010.

However, small changes in the code will make it compile.
Just replace {} by () in constructor line + make `main()` return something (dunno if that's specific to C++11, but my compiler did not want to compile with a `void` main).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
//using namespace std; commented, it's useless and confusing


class vector{
public:
    vector(int s) : elem(new double[s]), sz(s) {}
    double& operator[](int i) {return elem[i];}
    int size() {return sz;}
private:
    double* elem;
    int sz;
};


int main()
{
    vector v(6);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This may fail to compile, as it is ambiguous whether `vector` means `std::vector` or `::vector`. (Although `<vector>` isn't included, standard headers are allowed to include any other standard header). I'd suggest not doing `using namespace std;`, and/or calling this class something else.

Answer (score 1):

The same code works in VS2013. You are using C++ 11 specific code and probably the cl on your VS2010 does not know C++11.

This line is C++ 11 like:

```
vector(int s) :elem{new double[s]}, sz{s} {}
```

Comment: Can you look at my edited post? I tried it on VS2013.